# How to create Oracle database project using Visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle

All,

I have Oracle database project in VS2008. Now i upgraded my project to VS2010.While trying to create a database project , i can see i can't select any other Data source other than SQL Server. But in VS2008 i have option to select different data source.

I read about Toad Extension for Visual Studio and but its also not supported anymore.

http://www.toadworld.com/Blogs/tabid/67/EntryId/519/Creating-an-Oracle-Project-with-Toad-Extension-for-Visual-Studio.aspx

http://toadworld.com/Blogs/tabid/67/EntryId/876/What-happened-to-Toad-Extension-for-Visual-Studio.aspx

How can i set up oracle database project in VS2010. Is there any way through TFS?

Any suggestions??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may want to install the Oracle Data Provider for .NET. (ODP.NET)

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

EDIT:
also you may want to check this one that supports entity framework

http://www.devart.com/news/2008/directs475.html

Comment: I do have ODP.NET in my system.

Comment: this article shows how to connect with ODP.NET. hope this helps...
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/vs2010-oracle-dev-410461.html

Comment: This shows how to connect to ODP.Net. What im looking for is create a database project and connect to oracle database through vs 2010

Comment: Gotcha, then I believe you need the Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (ODT), so you can see it in your Server Explorer inside VS.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html