# how to create oracle database project in Visual studio 2013

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I was trying to create a new oracle Database project in Visual studio 2013 but not able to find the right framework to do so. The closest I can find in VS 2013 is "SQLserver Database project" , which is not Oracle.
I am looking for a solution(plug-in/ tutorial) to create the same from couple of days but didn't get anything helpful.
following are the closest but didn't help for a beginner like me :
[How to create Oracle database project using Visual studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807342/how-to-create-oracle-database-project-using-visual-studio-2010)
[How to create a database project in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654286/how-to-create-a-database-project-in-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Ultimate/Enterprise editions of Visual Studio, here is the information you need to connect.

**Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (ODT)** is a tightly integrated "Add-in" for Microsoft Visual Studio. Download ODT here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index-097110.html

Then, connect your application to an Oracle database using the .NET Framework Data Provider for Oracle. [[source]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xexk8kx3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

1. In the Choose Data Source dialog box, select Oracle Database, and click OK.

   If the Add Connection dialog box opens, and the Data source is not Oracle Database, click Change to open the Choose/Change Data Source dialog box. For more information, see Choose/Change Data Source Dialog Box.
2. Type the name of the server where the database you want to access is located.
3. Type the User name and Password used to access the database, if required. For more information, see Add/Modify Connection (Oracle).
4. Click OK.

Comment: This tells how to create an Oracle database connection, not an Oracle database project.